# How to avoid taking address of a temporary variable?

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, runtime-error, compiler-warnings, temporary-objects

The way my code is currently set up, I feel that I have to choose between a segmentation fault and making a pointer to a temporary object.  The code is below:

```
#include <memory>
#include <cstddef>
#include <iostream>

template <typename T> class Node;

template <typename T> class List {
    public:
        typedef std::size_t size_type;
        typedef T value_type;
        typedef T& reference;
        typedef const T& const_reference;

        class iterator {
            public:
                iterator() {
                    isNull = true;
                }
                iterator(const T val) {
                    isNull = false;
                    data = val;
                    prev = this;
                    next = &iterator();  #PROBLEMATIC LINE
                }
                iterator operator++() {
                    if(this->next->isNull)
                        return iterator();
                    iterator old_it = *this;
                    this->prev = &old_it;
                    this->next = this->next->next;
                    this->data = this->next->data;
                    return *this;
                }
                T& operator*() {
                    return data;
                }
                iterator* next;
                iterator* prev;
                T data;
                bool isNull;
        };

        List() {
            _begin = iterator();
            _end = _begin;
        }

        List(size_type n, T val) {
            _begin = iterator(val);
            _end = *(_begin.next);
            _end.prev = &_begin;
        }

        void push_back(T val) {
            iterator temp = iterator();
            _end.data = val;
            _end.next = &temp;
            temp.prev = &_end;
            _end = temp;
        }

        iterator begin() {return _begin;}
        iterator end() {return _end;}
    private:
        iterator _begin;
        iterator _end;
};

int main() {
    List<int> derp= List<int>(3,3);
    List<int>::iterator i = derp.begin();
    std::cout << *i;
    derp.push_back(4);
    std::cout << i.data;
    ++i;
    std::cout << *i;
}
```

The above takes the address of a temporary variable.  When I change the problematic line from

```
next = &iterator();
```

to

```
*next = iterator();
```

The code gets a segmentation fault, but I don't know why.  Any help would be appreciated.  As well as any egregious flaws in the code that you might happen to notice.

Comment: This is messed up. First, nodes are nodes, iterators are iterators. Don't mix the two. In a linked list, nodes store the actual data; iterators should simply point to the node. Second, to indicate that a node is the last in the list, just set `next` to `nullptr`.

Comment: you need to allocate memory for `next` before you dereference it.

Comment: Also, look at your `push_back`. You create an "iterator" on the stack, sets up the links to point to that "iterator", and then at the end of the function the "iterator" gets destroyed and you have a dangling pointer. Your nodes need to be allocated with `new` and freed with `delete` in the linked list's destructor, which also means that you need to write proper copy constructor and copy assignment operators.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first error is because you have to find a place to store the created object, before you can store a pointer to it. A temporary object will disappear -- you have to put it somewhere.

The second error is because have to initialise a pointer before you can dereference it. It has to point to something.

But there is a conceptual problem. An iterator is an object that is the logical equivalent of a pointer. A pointer-to-iterator would be equivalent to pointer-to-pointer. So your next and prev members should either be pointer-to-node or iterator, not pointer-to-iterator.

If you can make your code work the way you want with either of these, the other problems will go away. I don't really get the point of the whole thing, so I can't tell you how to do that.

Comment: So you're saying that I should split the code into Node and Iterator classes?  Because an iterator can't store an iterator as attribute, cuz that would take infinite memory?

Comment: Could be, but I don't really understand your goals so I don't know. There is no such thing as infinite memory, but no, a type cannot contain an instance of itself. Thing and pointer to thing are different.

Answer (score 0):

*next = iterator() leads to segmentation fault because you use a uninitialized pointer.
next = &iterator() is also very bad.See this:[Temporary Objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/a8kfxa78(v=vs.100).aspx)

just assign next to NULL;